# Array filter method passed data type rather than predicate

Tags: javascript

I have an array which looks like:

```
var containers = [2,0,false,"", '12', true];
```

When `filter` method is used like following :

```
var containers = containers.filter(Boolean);
console.log(containers);
```

It prints: `[ 2, '12', true ]`
This holds true even if `Number`, `String` or `Object` is passed to `filter` function. As per my understanding `filter` function accepts a function which is a predicate. However here it accepts a primitive data type. Can anyone please explain about this behavior?

Comment: I get different results for `String` and `Object`, so I don't really understand what you think you're asking

Comment: My question is - filter function accepts a function which is a predicate. But here it is accepting datatype as well. Is Boolean/String/Number a predicate?

Comment: Oh right, thought you were saying the results are always the same ... Boolean/String/Number/Object are functions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You passing the actual Boolean function, so you actually convert all values to a boolean and as `0` and `""` are falsy, you get the result like that...

Look at how this filter works in the loop:

```
Boolean(2); //true
Boolean(0); //false
Boolean(false); //false
Boolean(""); //false
Boolean(12); //true
Boolean(true); //true
```

I think what you are looking for is something like this instead:

```
var containers = [2,0, false ,"", '12', true];
var containers = containers.filter(function(v) { return "boolean" === typeof v});
console.log(containers); //[false, true]
```

Also these are list of falsy values in JavaScript for your reference:

1. **undefined**: if the value is not defined and it's `undefined`
2. **null**: if it's null, for example if a DOM element not exists...
3. **empty string**: `''`
4. **0**: number zero
5. **NaN**: not a number
6. **false**

Answer (score 1):

Boolean actually is a function, in addition to being a type. In fact, all types are technically also functions. The Boolean function will return true if the passed value is [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy). `2, "12", and true` are all "truthy" values, so they don't get filtered out.

Answer (score 0):

`Boolean` is a constructor function that accepts values and returns truthy values. Looking at the MDN docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean

Answer (score 0):

Primitive data types have a constructor, when you pass this constructor to filter, it applies the primitive functionality to each one of your array's values. Then it returns the result of that and filter will check its truthy value by applying its predicate.

For example, given this `containers.filter(String);`

String will get the first value, say 2, and apply its constructor and return "2".
Filter then will return the Boolean of "2" which evaluates to true,
confirming that the original 2 should be returned.

But for the fourth value in your array which is ""
is different.
String will evaluate to the same "", and Boolean("") will return false,
this means "" wont be included as a result of filter.

This applies to any primitive you apply to filter.

For ex. `containers.filter(Number);`.

in the case of the second element in the array which is 0,
Number(0) -> 0 -> Bollean(0) -> false -> not included as a result of filter